# Создание файла

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем.

Хочу узнать, как по нажатию кнопки создавать файл, например, (.txt) На C# (Windows Form).

Answer (score 7):

```
using System.IO;

string path = "";
if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);
```

P.S. В том же пространстве имен есть класс Directory для аналогичных операций

**Перенесено из комментария.**

Если нужно создать файл с текстом

1. Проверить существование файла и если его нет, то создать его
2. Если надо записать в файл - используй StreamWriter

Пример кода для записи текста в файл

```
string path = "";
string text = "";

if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);

StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(path);

output.WriteLine(text);
output.Close();
```

Comment: А как создать файл с какимто текстом или уже файл какой есть?

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Без проблем))

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text, [Encoding])
```